# How to give plugin access to specific role(s)

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

How do I restrict plugin access to a specific user role?

I wrote/installed a simple plugin that's listed in the left navbar in wp-admin.  However, I'd like to only have it show for specific roles.

I have the User Role Editor plugin installed.  It seems the way to do this is to add code to my plugin that creates a capability, and then use User Role Editor to assign that capability to the desired role(s).

Is this correct?  If so, how do I code that capability?  If not, how can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: "listed in the left navbar in wp-admin" - how did you add the menu? Using `add_menu_page()`, `add_submenu_page()`, or?

Comment: It's added using add_object_page()

Comment: As the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_object_page/) says, you should use [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) instead. And you can use the 3rd parameter to restrict the access to the admin menu and the page for that menu.